# Mongo - How can a narrower query be slower than a generic one?

Tags: mongodb

This is executed immediately:

```
db.mycollection.find({ strField: 'AAA'}).count()
```

And this takes a lot to finish:

```
db.mycollection.find({ strField: 'AAA', dateTimeField: { $exists: true }}).count()
```

This is how I created my index:

```
db.mycollection.createIndex({strField: 1, dateTimeField: 1}, { sparse: true })
```

But it doesn't work even using `hint(indexName)`

Why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ $exists: true }` query predicate is problematic, especially if there are documents in the collection for which that field does not exist.

When MongoDB creates an index entry for a document, it collects all of the field values according to the index spec, and concatenates them.

If a field is not present in the document, the index stores `null` in that field's position.
If the field is explicitly set to `null`, it also stores `null` in that field's position.

This means that these 2 documents will have identical entries in the index:

```
{ strField: 'AAA', dateTimeField: null}
{ strField: 'AAA'}
```

Note that even with the index being sparse, both documents will be indexed since at least one of the indexes fields exists in each document.

When testing `{dateTimeFied:{$exists:true}}`, the first document will match, while the second will not.

When processing a `count` query using an index, if the query can be satisfied by scanning a single range of the index, the query executor can use a count_scan stage, and get the correct result without loading a single document from disk.

Because the executor cannot definitively tell from the index whether or not the field exists, it cannot use a count_scan, and must instead use an ordinary ixscan followed by a fetch stage, and load all of the matching documents from disk in order to arrive at the correct count.

In the case of the first query, the executor would have been able to use a count_scan, while the second would have had to examine all of the documents.  You should be able to see this by running `explain` with the executionStats option on each query.

One way to avoid this pitfall is to take advantage of the fact that MongoDB query operators are type-sensitive.  This means that this query will match any document where dateTimeField is greater than epoch 0, **and a timestamp**:

```
db.mycollection.find({ strField: 'AAA', dateTimeField: { $gte: new ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z") }}).count()
```

This will allow the query executor to count all of the documents that have the matching string and contain a date, but will exclude documents that contain a dateTimeField with a numeric or string value.

Comment: `$exists:false` works by removing the `sparse` option